# could not open my ontology manually realized with protégé

Tags: xml, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

When I open my ontology manually realized , protégé displays this error:

```
OWL/XML sytax:
Attribute not found: IRI (Line 29)
RDF/XML syntax:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/pizza.owl; lineNumber: 350; columnNumber: 85; Un caractère XML non valide (Unicode : 0xc) a été détecté dans le contenu d'élément du document.
```

How can i open it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Comment: Like the error says, there is an invalid character in line 350, column 85

Comment: It looks very much about programming to me

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your file, the XML might declare a different encoding than the one actually used, or it might have been corrupted during download. I assume it's a pizza ontology example?

Please add the first line of the XML file to the question, and, if you have downloaded the file, the original URL. If you've modified the file itself, please open an issue on the OWLAPI github page with the file so we can work out if it's a bug or a problem with the file contents.