# dotNetRDF owl file encoding for chinese

Tags: encoding, rdf, owl, dotnetrdf

I have a owl file generated by Protege. Some classes' name and property name contain Chinese words like "苹果".

It's ok when I just open the owl file. However, when I usw OntologyGraph to load the owl file and foreach for OntologyClass, it shows error codes.

I want to ask, does dotnetrdf support chinese? How can I set the encoding style by dotnetrdf

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the file encoding, similar to the one reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959202/could-not-open-my-ontology-manually-realized-with-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9).

A Protege .owl file is an XML file that should contain a first line that specifies what the file encoding is. If that line is either missing or specifies an incorrect encoding for the file then dotNetRDF will potentially misread the file, leading to errors.